# WSO2 Redirect to login on failed SAML authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

WSO2IS 5.3.0: I have a service provider that is SAML inbound and multi-step local authentication outbound (the first step is BasicAuthenticator, and the second is custom code). I am running into an issue where, if the second step fails, the user goes to a generic "error" screen (this is samlsso_notification.do). I want the user to be redirected BACK to the login page to have to start the auth process over (WITH the error code from my authentication step, which [I can't seem to customize in the SAMLResponse](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-saml/blob/5.3.x/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/saml/servlet/SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java#L863)). Any advice on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you go inside `<product_home>`/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint you will find mapping .jsp for samlsso_notification.do as samlsso_notification.jsp from there you can write jsp redirection to login page. You have stat, statusMessage as context information.

Comment: How can I pass a custom status message through? It seems like the message may be hardcoded (see link above)